# jquery not working with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using following jquery method

```
$('form').submit(function(){    
    $('#universities_selected option').each(function(i) {    
       $(this).attr("selected", "selected");    
    });
});
```

when we submit form this method is called and it checks all the entries in multi select list "universities_selected" and set them as selected....

It works fine in firefox but not working in google chrome.

Comment: Please indent your code fragments with 4 spaces. Just select the text and click on the `10101`-button and it will do it for you. It makes the code much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your question:

http://www.corbensproducts.com/cgblog/49/jQuery-and-form-submit-in-Chrome.html